# Optimize NSFetchedResultsController fetch

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an NSFetchedResultsController and a large amount of data stored in Core Data which the fetched results controller must fetch. There are about 46,000 items it will end up fetching. The problem is that the fetch takes well over 8 seconds, and the entire time, the UI is frozen because we have to fetch on the main thread. I was wondering if there is something I can do to speed this up?

I am sorting the objects by their creation date, the fetch request has a batch size of 100, and the predicate is not overly complex. It filters the objects by their UID, type, and their owner's UID.

Since the user can search, the fetch predicate will change and so having a cache on the fetched results controller seems pointless when it simply gets deleted every time the fetch predicate changes.

It is directly related to the number of objects in Core Data because switching to an account that has fewer objects decreases the fetch time dramatically. (6000 objects takes less than a second). Is there any way to make this more scalable? My code follows:

```
- (NSFetchRequest *)getFetchRequest
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest requestWithEntityName:@"Photo"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[self getFetchPredicates]];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:100];
    return fetchRequest;
}

- (NSPredicate *)getFetchPredicates {
    NSMutableArray *predicates = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"life_uid == %@",[[LoginManager shared] currentLifeUID]],
                                  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(type == %@) OR (type == %@)", TLTypeImage, TLTypeVideo],
                                  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY stories.permission.owner_person_uid == %@ OR stories.@count == 0)", [[LoginManager shared] currentPersonUID]],
                                  nil];
    NSArray *filteredMomentIDs = [[self searchTerms] objectForKey:TLLibraryViewControllerSearchTermsPhotoIDsKey];
    if ([filteredMomentIDs count] > 0 && [self searchMode] == kTLLibrarySearchModeTag)
    {
        [predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uid in %@", filteredIDs]];
    }
    return [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could add (a) your predicate, and (b) the types of the fields you're searching on (string, integer, etc).

Comment: Did you try to set an index on the attributes used in the fetch predicate?

Comment: You mention your predicate filters by '...their owner's UID'. In my experience relationships can have a big impact on fetch performance. Might be worth testing the effect on speed by removing that part of the predicate.

Comment: Yes, the attributes used in the fetch predicate are indexed. I'll edit my question momentarily with code.

Comment: I timed the fetch with and without the "ANY stories.permission.owner_person_uid" predicate, and it's roughly 4 seconds. That's still entirely too long for the UI to be unresponsive. Definitely better, but unfortunately that predicate is necessary.

Comment: What is the type of uid? String, numeric? It's important.

Comment: All the properties in the fetch predicates are strings.

Answer (score 3):

Since you explain (in a comment) that all the attributes are strings, you may have a hard time improving the situation. You're doing a **lot** of string comparisons in that fetch-- 46k records multiplied by at least 3 for the first two predicates, plus more depending on how many `stories` relationships there are on average. That's the main reason for your performance issues-- doing that many string comparisons is going to be a bottleneck.

A couple of things that may help:

- In the third predicate you're looking at `@"(ANY stories.permission.owner_person_uid == %@ OR stories.@count == 0)"`. Predicates are evaluated left to right. Numeric comparisons are faster than string comparisons, so put the `@count` check first. If it's true then the second half won't need to be evaluated, and you'll skip a whole lot of string comparisons.
- The left-to-right thing also applies to the order of your `NSPredicate` instances. You probably have some idea what the data looks like-- make sure that the **most restrictive** predicate (i.e. the one that the largest number of objects will *not* pass) is the first one in the list. Then the second-most restrictive, etc. Since you're and-ing the predicates together, an instance fails the first predicate won't need to be checked against the others. Filter out objects as early as possible in the predicate chain.

Probably the easiest gain is by changing the order in the third predicate and then moving it to the front of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could always de-normalize your data model a little if this is really essential for performance. You could put add a copy of the owner_person_uid attribute onto the stories object. That way the predicate would not have to traverse so many relationships.

This solution would require that you always update the related object if you change one of the properties.